# Proof that the rationals are dense in the reals

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, solution-verification

Here is my understanding: let $x,y$ be real.

W.L.O.G, $x<y$; then consider the difference between $x$ and $y$, $y-x$. If the difference is greater than 1 then we are done because there is an integer between them. Otherwise, multiply them by some large enough integer $n$ so that their difference after multiplication is greater than 1. Then there is an integer $m$ between them: $nx<m<ny$. from that we divide all side of inequality by n to conclude the proof!

Comment: That proof is just fine as far as it goes. Now use it to show that there are rationals arbitrarily close to any given real number.

Comment: I originally followed the proof given in analysis problem book but I never understood what they did. Because they didn't say why they are doing what they are doing.  But I understand it now. I Wish they could have said it like what I wrote

Comment: This argument shows that there is a rational between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.  I give it full marks.

Comment: How do you know that there is an integer $n$ large enough so that "their difference after multiplication is greater than 1".  Are you citing something you have been given? If so, what? Can you cite it?  Or are you assuming it is obvious.  If so can you prove it?  ... Also, *is* this the definition of dense; that between any two real numbers there is a rational number?  Or is it, as Ethan Bolker, seems to believe; that given any real number there are rational numbers arbitrarily close. (Actually that is *almost* the definition of real numbers...)

Comment: Okay, I'm going to be *really* nitpicky.  Far more than any teacher ought to be a far more than you or any student deserves.  Well beyond the pale of reasonable nitpickiness... but how do you know that if $y- x > 1$ that there is an integer $K$ so that $x < K < y$?

Comment: For $n(y-x)>1$, we have $ n > \frac{1}{y-x}$. For this, I would go with Archimedean principal. I don't understand it much because it does seem obvious. For dense, I would go with any real number is a limit point of rational with means $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ has a rational in between?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ has difference greater than $1$, assuming that $y>x$, then the floor of y is greater than  to $y-1$ which is greater than $x$.

Comment: @user42493 Your last comment is just what you need to finish. There are ordered fields where Archimedes principle fails, so it's not obvious. You need to prove it from some simpler axioms, or assume it. You have the right conclusion for dense. You could post an answer to your own question now, and accept it, so it will no longer attract attention.